# Chef environment concepts

Tags: chef-infra

I need some lights about two concepts: `roles` and `environments`. I know what they stand for, nevertheless I don't quite figure out:

- Where should I set them up? On my workstation and then I need to upload them? Or I've to define them on my chef server?
- I've several recipes inside my `recipes` folder. Where should I define roles?

**EDIT**

Currently, I'm using this folder structure:

```
├───.delivery
│   └───build_cookbook
│       ├───data_bags
│       │   └───keys
│       ├───recipes
│       ├───secrets
│       └───test
│           └───...
├───.kitchen
│   ├───kitchen-vagrant
│   │   ├───kitchen-development-default-centos-72
│   │   │   └───...
│   │   └───kitchen-development-default-ubuntu-1604
│   │       └───...
│   └───logs
├───files
│   ├───elasticsearch
│   │   └───scripts
│   └───mongo
├───recipes
├───spec
│   └───unit
│       └───recipes
└───test
    ├───integration
    │   └───data_bags
    │       └───aws
    └───smoke
        └───default
```

And I'm using `berkshelf` in order to manage package cookbook dependencies and to upload my "cookbook" or "recipe" to my chef server.

What should I change in order to use environments, roles...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roles and environments are stored in the `roles` and `environments` directories respectively.

All code and json data on your infrastructure should be stored in a chef-repo. If you installed chef-dk ([the Chef Development Kit](https://docs.chef.io/install_dk.html)) on your workstation - which I highly suggest - you can generate such a chef-repo using the `chef generate repo` command. The structure of such a repo looks like this, and you should follow it even when not using `chef generate` (`README` files are optional :) ):

```
test
├── chefignore
├── cookbooks
│   ├── example
│   │   ├── attributes
│   │   │   └── default.rb
│   │   ├── metadata.rb
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   └── recipes
│   │       └── default.rb
│   └── README.md
├── data_bags
│   ├── example
│   │   └── example_item.json
│   └── README.md
├── environments
│   ├── example.json
│   └── README.md
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
└── roles
    ├── example.json
    └── README.md
```

You can then upload anything from those directories (files or whole folders) using `knife upload`.

Comment: could you take a look on my edited post? I'm using `berks`. Could you give some tips in order to adapt my current project structure? Remember I need to use environments and roles. Should I just add a `roles` and an `environments` folder to my current project structure. Should I re-create a new project structure?